# Migrating to Micro Front End with ASP.MET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, micro-frontend

I'm trying move from our monolith ui to micro front end.
We currently have a asp.net mvc application and what I want to achieve is the ability to have a container site that could call parts of the application, route based. But I cant seem to find any resource with this kind of application, and I'm starting to think its not possible. Not interested in an iFrame approach.

How would I go about re-using parts of this old site?

Comment: I'm interested in this topic as well. Specifically using an S3 bucket hosted front end app inside a server rendered razor page or MVC page that allows deployment between server app and front ends to be separate and allows to use a normal cookie authentication with a same site http only cookie for a simple yet very secure app that has good SEO, good UX and can easily leverage a simple asp.net core identity setup.